# Is it possible to reset a Cycler object

Tags: python, matplotlib

E.g., if shape of `lines1` and `lines2` were `(3,101)` with

```
 plt.plot(x, lines1, linewidth=3)
 plt.plot(x, lines2, linewidth=1)
```

I have a blue, green, red line with width equal to 3, and a cyan, magenta and yellow line with width equal to 1.

Because the data in `lines1` is connected pairwise to data in `lines2`, 
I'd like to reset the `Cycler` objet that controls the lines' color between the two `plot` instructions, so that I have  blue, green, red lines, width=3 followed by blue, green, red lines width=1 and there is a visual connection (the color) between the pairs of lines.

The `Cycler` object in question is a property of `axes`, exactly the `prop_cycle` property

```
In [28]: plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']
Out[28]: cycler('color', ['b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k'])
```

Is it possible to reset this `Cycler` object?

Answer (score 2):

Asking a question implies reaching a better understanding of the problem, doesn't it?

The statement below does the trick,

```
plt.gca().set_prop_cycle(plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'])
```

`<edit>`Even simpler,`plt.gca().set_prop_cycle(None)`, see **Addendum** below.`</edit>`

`matplotlib` has its internal consistency...

Example:

```
In [46]: %matplotlib
In [47]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
In [48]: import numpy as np
In [49]: x = np.linspace(0, 7, 101)
In [50]: y1 = np.array([np.sin(x+0.2*i*x) for i in range(2)])
In [51]: y2 = 0.9*y1+0.1
In [52]: plt.plot(x, y1.T, linewidth=3)
Out[52]: 
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f5118b759b0>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f5118b75b38>]
In [53]: plt.gca().set_prop_cycle(plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'])
In [54]: plt.plot(x, y2.T, linewidth=1)
Out[54]: 
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f511a3bec50>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f5118b1e898>]
In [55]:
```

[image]gives me

#### Addendum

At last I read the doc string of `.set_prop_cycle()`

> Set the property cycle for any future plot commands on this `Axes`.
>
> ```
> set_prop_cycle(arg)  
> set_prop_cycle(label, itr)  
> set_prop_cycle(label1=itr1[, label2=itr2[, ...]])
> ```
>
> Form 1 simply sets given `Cycler` object.
> [...]
> **Parameters**
> **arg** : Cycler
> Set the given Cycler.
> Can also be `None` to *reset* to the cycle defined by the current style.
> [...]

My code can be simplified:

```
plt.plot(x, y1, linewidth=3)
plt.gca().set_prop_cycle(None)
plt.plot(x, y2, linewidth=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The value in `plt.rcParams` is the underlying `Cycler` but the `Axes` objects hold a reference to an iterator over that object (see [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_base.py#L169), it is actually a `itertools.cycle` around the iterator so it never runs out).

If you are using the broadcasting in plot then you can do something like

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_prop_cycle((cycler('lw', [1, 3] *
                   cycler('color', ['b', 'g', 'r']))
ax.plot(x, lines1)
ax.plot(x, lines2)
```

To use a subset of the current default cycle

```
dflt_cy = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']
my_cy = cycler('lw', [1, 3]) * dflt_cy[:3]
```

(See [the docs](http://matplotlib.org/cycler/#slicing) for details)  will give you the same as above.

My suggestion here is do to something a bit more general if you can loop over your data one at a time:

```
from cycler import cycler
my_cycle = (cycler('lw', [1, 3] *
            cycler('color', ['b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k']))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for sty, data in zip(my_cycle(), my_data):
    ax.plot(x, data, **sty)
```

Comment: Your answer is useful but my question had a different twist in it... If you plot the two line sets in two subplots, the `Cycler` is reset automatically,  I want to do the same but using only one subplot, w/o having to guess which are the current defaults — that, given the introduction of `plt.style.use()` can be different from blue, green, red.

Comment: It is not so much reset, but is simply an entirely different iterator.  Also see my edit.

Comment: Also, mpl will do all sorts of things implicitly for you (which is great if you are typing this into a terminal) but I _strongly_ suggest writing your self helper functions that take in `def my_helper(ax, data, style)` which can then be very explicit about things.