# Assign specific colors to array columns without explicit iteration when plotting in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

It is helpful sometimes to do `plt.plot(x, y)` when `y` is a 2D array due to every column of `y` will be plotted against `x` automatically in the same subplot. In such a case, line colors are set by default. But is it possible to customize colors with something similar to `plt.plot(x, y, color=colors)` where now `colors` is an iterable?

For example, let's say I have three datasets that scatter around straight lines and want to plotted with fitting curves in such a way that each dataset and its fit share the same color.

```
np.random.seed(0)

# fake dataset
slope = [1, 2, 3]
X = np.arange(10) 
Y = slope * X[:,None] + np.random.randn(10,3)

# fitting lines
params = np.polyfit(X, Y, deg=1)
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)
y = np.polyval(params, x[:,None])
```

I would like to get the ouput of the following code without having to iterate manually.

```
colors = ['b', 'r', 'g']
for i in range(3):
    plt.plot(X, Y[:,i], '.', color=colors[i])
    plt.plot(x, y[:,i], color=colors[i])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

"reset" the properties cycler

```
...
plt.plot(x, Y, '.')
plt.gca().set_prop_cycle(None)
plt.plot(x, y)
...
```

---

For an explanation, see [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38111647/2749397).